# How to use Tumblr as back end for iOS App

Tags: tumblr, backend

I'm considering creating a iOS app to simplify and streamline consumption of my multi-topic blog, which currently lives on Tumblr. Is there anyway to pull content from my Tumblr account so I can use it as my backend (i.e I can still update my app with the Tumblr interface)? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; you can use [the Tumblr API](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2).